# Merge and Reformat JSON files using jq

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have two different JSON files returned with Python code for Twitter data. The first JSON file is in the form below:

**A.json**

```
{"tweet_id": "1212024242595926028", "username": "THPDPIO", "created_at": "2019-12- 
31T14:54:32.000Z", "tweets": {"0": "Folks, it\u2019s simple!! You know what to do and 
what not to do...don\u2019t drink and drive and you don\u2019t have to worry about 
ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a small part of it...think about the 
possibility killing someone or killing yourself...again it\u2019s simple... 
\ud83d\ude42 #stayhome"}}
{"tweet_id": "1212024242595926028", "username": "TheAliciaRanae", "created_at": 
"2019-12-31T15:11:51.000Z", "tweets": {"1": "@THPDPIO Stay home and drink and pass 
out and leave everyone else alone lol that\u2019s what I\u2019ll be doing lol HAPPY 
NEW YEAR!"}}
{"tweet_id": "1212024242595926028", "username": "duane4343", "created_at": "2019-12- 
31T15:21:37.000Z", "tweets": {"1": "@THPDPIO Happy New Year"}}
{"tweet_id": "1212024242595926028", "username": "HollyBr34731868", "created_at": 
"2019-12-31T15:24:25.000Z", "tweets": {"1": "@THPDPIO Hope everyone has a safe 
night."}}

{"tweet_id": "1211503874395254785", "username": "UNDPoliceDept", "created_at": "2019- 
12-30T04:26:46.000Z", "tweets": {"0": "Typical North Dakotan.... #BestCopsAround 
#NoTravelAdvised #StayHome"}}
{"tweet_id": "1211503874395254785", "username": "UNDPoliceDept", "created_at": "2019- 
12-30T04:27:40.000Z", "tweets": {"1": "@NDHighwayPatrol"}}
{"tweet_id": "1211503874395254785", "username": "BorgenEthan", "created_at": "2019- 
12-30T05:28:48.000Z", "tweets": {"1": "@UNDPoliceDept Nah i definitely look like the 
first one"}}
```

With jq, i wrote some commands to choose the fields I want {NB: This was done in https://jqplay.org} with the command `{tweet_id: .tweet_id, username: .username, reply: .tweets} | group_by(.tweet_id)` but I get the error that

> q: error (at :1): Cannot index string with string "tweet_id"

My **desired output** is to get the sample below for the first file:

```
{
"tweet_id": "1212024242595926028",
"username": "THPDPIO",
"reply": {
  "0": "Folks, it’s simple!! You know what to do and what not to do...don’t drink and drive and you don’t have to worry about ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a small part of it...think about the possibility killing someone or killing yourself...again it’s simple...  #stayhome",
  "1": "@THPDPIO Stay home and drink and pass out and leave everyone else alone lol that’s what I’ll be doing lol HAPPY NEW YEAR!",
  "1": "@THPDPIO Happy New Year",
  "1": "@THPDPIO Hope everyone has a safe night."
}}
```

**My issue: To have all replies linked to a particular tweet_id**

For the 2nd file

**B.json**

```
{
"author_id": 80083199,
"tweet_id": 1212150612026151000,
"username": "CTVdavidspence",
"author_followers": 19572,
"author_tweets": 73406,
"author_description": "Retired broadcast Meteorologist. 2017 RTDNA Lifetime 
Achievement Award. Best of Calgary 2018, 2019.  AHS Patient and Family Advisor 
(volunteer)",
"author_location": "Calgary",
"text": "The Trans Canada Highway near #Sicamous BC.  #stayhome   Image from 
@DriveBC.",
"created_at": 1577834201000,
"retweets": 12,
"replies": 4,
"likes": 27,
"quote_count": 0}
{
"author_id": 848959032370921500,
"tweet_id": 1212024242595926000,
"username": "THPDPIO",
"author_followers": 4626,
"author_tweets": 2383,
"author_description": "Police Sgt.",
"author_location": "Terre Haute, IN",
"text": "Folks, it’s simple!! You know what to do and what not to do...don’t drink 
 and drive and you don’t have to worry about ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a 
 small part of it...think about the possibility killing someone or killing 
 yourself...again it’s simple... \n#stayhome",
"created_at": 1577804072000,
"retweets": 11,
"replies": 9,
"likes": 84,
"quote_count": 1}
```

I will want to merge my final json file such that the tweet_id becomes the reference and the replies and username becomes the keys to merge them. So the final json file will be like the one below:

```
{
"author_id": 848959032370921500,
"tweet_id": 1212024242595926000,
"username": "THPDPIO",
"author_followers": 4626,
"author_tweets": 2383,
"author_description": "Police Sgt.",
"author_location": "Terre Haute, IN",
"text": "Folks, it’s simple!! You know what to do and what not to do...don’t drink 
 and drive and you don’t have to worry about ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a 
 small part of it...think about the possibility killing someone or killing 
 yourself...again it’s simple... \n#stayhome",
"created_at": 1577804072000,
"retweets": 11,
"replies": 9,
"likes": 84,
"quote_count": 1,
"reply": {
  "0": "Folks, it’s simple!! You know what to do and what not to do...don’t drink and 
  drive and you don’t have to worry about ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a 
  small part of it...think about the possibility killing someone or killing 
  yourself...again it’s simple...  #stayhome",
  "1": "@THPDPIO Stay home and drink and pass out and leave everyone else alone lol 
  that’s what I’ll be doing lol HAPPY NEW YEAR!",
  "1": "@THPDPIO Happy New Year",
  "1": "@THPDPIO Hope everyone has a safe night."
}}
```

I will appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: JSON processors in general, jq in particular, will eliminate all (but one) duplicate keys in an object. Consider designing `.reply` as an array.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines, with an emphasis on the "m".  Also, SO works best when each posted Q focuses on just one Q.  If you have closely related questions, it sometimes works best to post just one, and then wait for an answer before posting the next.  And perhaps the answer to the first will somehow resolve the follow-up question.

Comment: @pmf Yes I had thought of that, I will make it an array of objects. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the second issue, you could employ `JOIN` on `B.json` and a custom index (eg. from the first issue) on `A.json`:

```bash
jq --slurpfile A A.json --slurpfile B B.json -n '
  JOIN(
    $A | reduce group_by(.tweet_id)[] as $g (
      {}; .[$g[0].tweet_id].reply += ($g | map(.tweets))
    );
    $B[]; .tweet_id | @text; add
  )
'
```

```json
{
  "author_id": 80083199,
  "tweet_id": 1212150612026151000,
  "username": "CTVdavidspence",
  "author_followers": 19572,
  "author_tweets": 73406,
  "author_description": "Retired broadcast Meteorologist. 2017 RTDNA Lifetime Achievement Award. Best of Calgary 2018, 2019.  AHS Patient and Family Advisor (volunteer)",
  "author_location": "Calgary",
  "text": "The Trans Canada Highway near #Sicamous BC.  #stayhome   Image from @DriveBC.",
  "created_at": 1577834201000,
  "retweets": 12,
  "replies": 4,
  "likes": 27,
  "quote_count": 0
}
{
  "author_id": 848959032370921500,
  "tweet_id": 1212024242595926000,
  "username": "THPDPIO",
  "author_followers": 4626,
  "author_tweets": 2383,
  "author_description": "Police Sgt.",
  "author_location": "Terre Haute, IN",
  "text": "Folks, it’s simple!! You know what to do and what not to do...don’t drink  and drive and you don’t have to worry about ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a  small part of it...think about the possibility killing someone or killing  yourself...again it’s simple... \n#stayhome",
  "created_at": 1577804072000,
  "retweets": 11,
  "replies": 9,
  "likes": 84,
  "quote_count": 1,
  "reply": [
    {
      "0": "Folks, it’s simple!! You know what to do and what not to do...don’t drink and drive and you don’t have to worry about ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a small part of it...think about the possibility killing someone or killing yourself...again it’s simple...  #stayhome"
    },
    {
      "1": "@THPDPIO Stay home and drink and pass out and leave everyone else alone lol that’s what I’ll be doing lol HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
    },
    {
      "1": "@THPDPIO Happy New Year"
    },
    {
      "1": "@THPDPIO Hope everyone has a safe night."
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4RNQz4mEPZH)

Comment: For the code you provided on jq, i get this error `jq: error (at <unknown>): Cannot index array with string "tweet_id"` for which I know that the tweet_id by the A.json file returns a string in quotes, I tried passing the `| tonumber` but it still did not work on that. Any reason why. @pmf

Comment: @MichaelMaverick This is the error message that occurs when you are trying to access an array (as such having no fields) using a field name (`.tweet_id` in this case). My code uses `.tweet_id` twice, once on each input file. My guess is that either one (or both) input files are in fact arrays, not streams (as shown in your sample data), or you have inserted a `--slurp` or `-s` option producing an array (whereas I didn't in my code).

Comment: No I did not change any option in your code except my filenames. However from the demo you added, I realized that you converted the two inputs to an array which is not like that according to my use-case. Could that be the reason? @pmf

Comment: @MichaelMaverick I did that for the demo because on jqplay.org there is no means to `--slurpfile` an input file. Consequently I didn't use `$A` and `$B` in the demo, but `.` and `input`. But that shouldn't make any difference, in fact with your sample files saved into actual files `A.json` and `B.json`, the above code produces the desired content on my machine. (What I have changed though is replacing the IDs `"1212024242595926028"` to `"1212024242595926000"` (turning the final `28` into `00`) in `A.json` in order to have actual matchings, as from the sample alone there wouldn't be any match.)

Comment: I have a last question with regards to the output, assuming now that I have the replies as an array, I will like to identify each reply with the user(.username) as well as the created date(.created_at) but when I place it within the code like this `($g | map(.tweets, {username:.username, created_at:.created_at})` it maps those outside the object block for the replies, how do I attach it to the respective object. Thank you @pmf, your response has been helpful. @pmf

Comment: @MichaelMaverick You may want to pull the `.tweets` also inside the new object: `$g | map({username, created_at, tweets})` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fBR1k1BppP4). Or merge the `.tweets` object into the one with the other two fields: `$g | map({username, created_at} + .tweets)` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VxWM8-ZqkM3).

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. The second use-case was my objective. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have a concern because I am working with a lot of lines of data but it doesn't seem to work out. With the [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EWiRjWMXxBX) I have populated it with a lot of data but it does not seem to group it with the replies. Could there be any reason why?

Comment: @MichaelMaverick This was indeed strange. I had to make some tests to find out. It turned out to be the same overflow issue I mentioned earlier. Your big demo [works](https://jqplay.org/s/2FB1Il0nnP2) when beforehand all `.tweet_id` numbers are converted into strings (surrounded by quotes). I had to do it manually, though, as I wasn't able to achieve this programmatically (e.g. [using](https://jqplay.org/s/c4SYpp1dkNk) `.tweet_id |= @text`) because the numbers get rounded (e.g. `1217156734722232324`, which would have some matches, to `"1217156734722232300"`, which will have no pair).

Comment: Therefore, my suggestion would be to either use [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) as suggested by peak (I just tested it locally with your big data, and it works without the need for conversion), or use any external tools to perform the mandatory conversion into strings in preparation for being used with standard `jq`.

Comment: so my finalized solution was to convert the ids into strings. I installed the gojq and was running some of the syntaxes but I was wondering if the syntax for the gojq will be the same as the jq. But I am grateful you stepped through to explain a lot of things to me now. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelMaverick I almost exclusively use standard `jq`, but on all my (few) excursions to `gojq` I could effortlessly use standard `jq` syntax. To me, the most conspicuous (UI) difference was some of the additional command-line options such as `--yaml-input` and `--yaml-output`. Maybe @peak can say more on this, as he is more experienced with `gojq`.

Comment: Thank you. I went through their documentation and studied it along, especially the part where they make some differences between `jq` and `gojq`. Thank you and hoping @peak steps in with some more explanations. Gracias

Comment: @MichaelMaverick Just stumbled upon a list of "Most Salient Differences" in the [Regarding gojq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Regarding-gojq) section of the jq wiki, and wanted to share it with you in case you didn't know of it either. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I am giving a read and will come back with questions in case I have any. Thank you once again.

Comment: I am changing my use-case for the JSON with jq and wanted you to check something on this [link](https://jqplay.org/s/2yXslY_kl0P) . I want to first nest the first json file using the parent_tweet_id and then afterwards merge with the second json file using the conversation_id from the a.json which matches the tweet_id of b.json. For clarity, I am representing a sample output to this [link](http://jsonblob.com/1030873176925814784). The objective is to make sure replies are connected to their parents using the parent_id which is the tweet_id of the previous.

Comment: Can you check on this post above for me.

Comment: @MichaelMaverick Why is tweet id 1344450393586204672 whose parent id is 1344435985279459334 listed as child of id 1344453741773111306 in the desired output? Fixed it assuming it was a typo. Then, you need some sort of recursion to master arbitrary thread lengths. Here's one way to do it with functions `def f`: `map(.tweets + del(.tweets)) | INDEX(.tweet_id) as $tweets | map(select(.parent_tweet_id != .tweet_id)) | INDEX(.parent_tweet_id) as $replies | def f: . + ($replies[.tweet_id]? | {reply: f} // {}); input | map(.thread = [$tweets[.tweet_id] | f])` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/I-sCy7lwbEB)

Comment: Thank you for reverting, for the Demo you created, I added another object to test the use case but I realized if I have two tweet replies of the same parent_tweet_id, it disregards all and assigns only the last one. You can check the Demo link you shared, I added some data objects to it. Also, I understand recursion in JavaScript, in a use case like this, how will I approach the problem from a divide and conquer stand-point. Thank you for your prompt response **Conversation_ID: `1344432368677896192`**

Comment: @MichaelMaverick The approach I took (using `INDEX` to assign exactly one item to an ID) was based on the sample and desired outcome you provided (which only contained straight threads without branches). If you want to improve on the samples (as for more accuracy wrt your actual data) you will have to create new jqplay instances (you cannot just "add" to an existing instance, it won't be updated/propagated). Lastly, your data structures are quite cumbersome, and dependencies are not always explicit or intuitive. Could you please add some doc to your desired output (edge cases etc.). Thank you.

Comment: I created a doc to outline the objective I am trying to achieve clearly explained. Kindly let me know if this makes it more clearer. Also, I didn't know if I cannot populate with the data unless I create a new jqplay instance. This [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17onJcCjWbyoUj5w7OaSjY3imCSMzPho8_I4RzJQKEN0/edit?usp=sharing) contains the document I have outlined. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This response deals with the first issue:

> To have all replies linked to a particular tweet_id

As pointed out by @pmf, your sample output won't achieve the goal. Also, `group_by` expects an array as input. Consider therefore:

```
< A.json jq -n '
  def accumulate_by(stream; f):
    reduce stream as $x ({}; (f + [$x|f]) as $v | . + $x | f = $v );
    
  [inputs | {tweet_id, username, reply: .tweets}] | group_by(.tweet_id)
  | map( accumulate_by(.[]; .reply ))
'
```

Note that, by design, this ignores "collisions" in the value of .username; you may need to consider this further.  Anyway, with your sample, the result would be:

```
[
  {
    "tweet_id": "1211503874395254785",
    "username": "BorgenEthan",
    "reply": [
      {
        "0": "Typical North Dakotan.... #BestCopsAround #NoTravelAdvised #StayHome"
      },
      {
        "1": "@NDHighwayPatrol"
      },
      {
        "1": "@UNDPoliceDept Nah i definitely look like the first one"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tweet_id": "1212024242595926028",
    "username": "HollyBr34731868",
    "reply": [
      {
        "0": "Folks, it’s simple!! You know what to do and what not to do...don’t drink and drive and you don’t have to worry about ANY consequences.  Btw...jail is just a small part of it...think about the possibility killing someone or killing yourself...again it’s simple...  #stayhome"
      },
      {
        "1": "@THPDPIO Stay home and drink and pass out and leave everyone else alone lol that’s what I’ll be doing lol HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
      },
      {
        "1": "@THPDPIO Happy New Year"
      },
      {
        "1": "@THPDPIO Hope everyone has a safe night."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: this solved my the first issue, but can you basically explain to me the function since am new to jq. Also I passed `[inputs | {tweet_id|number, username, reply: .tweets}]` to convert the tweet_id to a number instead of a string but had an error. Could there be any reason why?

Comment: You would have to write `tweet_id: (.tweet_id|tonumber)` instead of just `tweet_id`

Comment: Yessss. It worked. Thank you, I upvote your response as the solution for my first issue although not all.

Comment: @MichaelMaverick Be careful with applying `tonumber` to *long* strings (~ *large* numbers) as overflowing may occur. Using your IDs from above, try running `["1212024242595926000", "1212024242595926028"] | | ., map(tonumber) | .[0] == .[1]`. On [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/TQMmtaV8dpU) the string comparison yields `false` while the numeric one yields `true`. Therefore consider rather converting the numbers to strings instead (using `tostring` or `@text` (as I did), or [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29)).

Comment: Great higlighting this to me @pmf. I read that and literally understand it. Thank you for the heads-up.

Comment: Note that both the master version of jq and gojq (the Go implementation of jq) implement tonumber in a way that preserves precision.